# compare values in a column with another dataframe and create a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like df

| Name | cost | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | 300.0 | A1 |
| ram | 506.0 | B2 |
| sam | 300.0 | C4 |
| Adam | 289.0 | 1 |

I need to print output as below

| Name | cost | ID | Keyword |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | 300 | A1 | RF |
| ram | 506 | B2 | DD |
| sam | 300 | C4 | RF |
| Adam | 289 | 1 | Shared |

1. i want to create a new column with condition like if ID has integer values then in Keywords it should be Shared. If ID=A1 the Keyword=RF...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and some minor transformations:

```
out = (df.astype({'cost': int})
         .merge(df1.rename(columns={'Num_ID': 'ID', 'Operator': 'Keyword'}),
                on='ID', how='left')[df.columns.tolist() + ['Keyword']])
print(out)

# Output
   Name  cost  ID Keyword
0  john   300  A1      RF
1   ram   506  B2      DD
2   sam   300  C4      RF
```

Read [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Another solution:

```
out = df.assign(cost=df['cost'].astype(int), 
                Keyword=df['ID'].map(df1.set_index('Num_ID')['Operator']))
print(out)

# Output
   Name  cost  ID Keyword
0  john   300  A1      RF
1   ram   506  B2      DD
2   sam   300  C4      RF
```